# An unexpected error occurred during export

Tags: createjs, extendscript, flash-cc

I am using Adobe Flash Professional CC to convert flash games to HTML5.
When i export my animation an error pop up saying "**a JavaScript error occurred**", and in the output "**An unexpected error occurred during export. [JSX]**".
I search for an answer got few results on it including http://community.createjs.com/. But none of it solves the problem.

Comment: Make sure all your library object have unique names. When two object share the same name but exist in different folders, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Are you using the latest update for Flash CC? There used to be a number of things that could cause this error (mostly related to naming iirc), but all the known ones were fixed by Adobe. If you're able to isolate something that's still causing this issue, then it would be great to surface to Adobe so it can be fixed. I'm happy to help with passing any information on to them.

Comment: Thanx for the helpful comments @ Ferry I tired to isolated the error by deleting the objects that is used in the flash file and then trying to export the file. but still the  error occurs. How ever this method helped me solve a problem the I had when trying to run other exported flash files. which give a "out of memory" message.

Comment: @gskinner, I am still trying to solve the problem. If I find a way, I will let you know. Thanx for the tip

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was due to some Advanced Color Effects applied to the symbol (the ones where you mix alpha and RGB channels settings together). If I use effect styles like alpha or brightness, it works ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me the fix was just deleting one of my symbols from my stage.. When it was in my library it published fine, but bringing it to the stage gave me that error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that HTML5 canvas really doesn't like to support certain art assets. I had the same problem, but I realised that certain of my art elements had been created in Illustrator, with masks and paths. Once I got rid of them things started working properly

Comment: Yup. That fixed it completely. I had to re-touch up some of my art assets (background stuff that had weird masks and paths from illustrator that Java script just couldn't handle during compilation. Once I got rid of them, BOTH from the stage and the library everything worked perfectly. This problem had been really bugging me for 2 solid days, but solved now

Answer (score 0):

I recently struggled with this desperately trying to work out what was causing the problem.

The answer was a **custom easing curve set on a particular tween in a particular MovieClip**.

Incredibly hard to isolate, by deleting aspects of the project one by one.

Apparently that curve didn't play well. Weird thing is that I never defined a custom easing curve there, pretty sure. This may be the result of a CC update changing curve presets?